# Changing UILabel's size changes its font name

Tags: swift, uilabel, appdelegate, uifont, uiappearance

I wanted to change the default font of the app so I did

`UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 17)`

in the AppDelegate and it worked as expected until I tried to change the font size.

I tried changing the font size like so

```
categoryName.font = UIFont(name: categoryName.font.fontName, size: 17)
```

or `categoryName.font.fontWithSize(20)`

After changing the font sizes it changes the fontName and it printed this font name `.SFUIText` so just for a change I commented the

`UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 17)`

from the AppDelegate and changed the font from storyboard and worked well even after changing the font size.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.SFUIText** is the default **system** font hence you are getting the same result when you are assigning.

**Appearance** does not change the properties once they are in the window.
Create custom label class and use it.

Or simply use your font `UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 17)` to change the font size. it will work.

For appearance please check link **https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance**

Comment: ya so how to keep the same font which I have set globally for the UILabel?

Comment: Your solution is right UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 17) . But appearance does not change the properties once they are in window. whenever you want to change the font it use complete UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 17) to set as appearance not going to work. Or you can create custom label class and use it.